# What is this song in My Hero Academia Season 4 Episode 12?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

Does anyone know the song in *My Hero Academia* during Season 4 Episode 12, at approximately 18 minutes and 30 seconds into the episode? whenever Lemillion is trying to escape with Eri, but then tells her to run and keep going because he cant move anymore

Answer (score 0):

The track you were looking for is *Hidari wa Zettai Tsukawanee* from the 2nd OST.

I'm gonna assume you eventually found it, but I still thought I'd resurrect this to actually post the correct answer for anyone else who may be looking to find it, as it's an amazing, highly underrated track.

Answer (score -1):

*You Say Run* vocal ver. by Might⁺U ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GP6eLe-Uzak)), which is also played in *My Hero Academia Movie: Heroes Rising*.

Comment: -thats not the one , but thanks its still really good